# Sox stats and PHP using shell_exec

Tags: php, sox

i ran into some problems lately with SoX and PHP. I am a complete beginner in running command-line tools in PHP, so i try to describe the problem as good as i can:

So we have the following situation:

There is a .wav-file in the folder `[root]/demo/test.wav`

My php-file is located is located in `[root]/inc/classes.php`

So the php looks somewhat like this (really a minimal example)

```
function wav() {
    $output = shell_exec('sox ..\demo\test.wav -n stat');
    var_dump($output);
    echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
}
```

So if i run the function (and if i take a really huge .wav-file) it seems to "do" something, because the browser takes a long time to run the request.

But everything i receive is "NULL"

If i change the shell_exec-command to `shell_exec('sox -help')` it works.

So my question is: How come? xD

best regards

Comment: Use Linux? Or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one too. You were the only documented problem I could find on it. All I wanted was the mp3 duration.

```
shell_exec("sox test.mp3 -n stat") // was returning NULL
```

but

```
shell_exec("sox --i -D test.mp3") // worked!
```

No idea why.

Three months late, but this might save someone some time.

Comment: Hehe, thank you. I found the solution myself after a while and honestly completely forgot about this post :D...
The problem "seems" to me that what sox returns is not always in the same format. Some things come as an array, some as a single value.
I believe _-n -stat_ gives you an array of values while _--i -D_ just gives you a single value.